# Execute function on tap Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have an iOS APP and a push notifications system which sends programatically notifications to the storing their token in a database.

I have some views which I show or hide in the default View Controller. I would like to make the APP show a specific view when the user taps the notification. I have created a function, but I dont know how to make it work.

Comment: in push notification  payload, you can send extra custom data, you need to send the custom data accordingly and handle the views (show/hide) as per the data received inside that custom data

Comment: I recommend setting a notificationCenter observer in a UIViewController extension and have it listen from your appDelegate function that receive the notification and as mention from @AshwinShrestha use the data you send as viewcontroller identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch a push notifications inside `AppDelegate` and add Observer inside your controller file where you want to  show a specific view on tap.

Send push notification payload data in `userInfo` or `object` in `NotificationCenter.default.post`.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NewNotification") , object: nil, userInfo: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

Add Notification Observer in your controller file :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pushNotificationHandler(_:)) , name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NewNotification"), object: nil)
```

then call UI update method :

```
 func pushNotificationHandler(_ notification : NSNotification) {
   // self.udateUI() // Add code to show a specific view on tap.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate APNS delegate method make a check according to the userInfo you get with your notification/payload and then call that function either

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

 if response.notification.request.content.userInfo["ViewType"] as! String == "ShowNotificationView" {
 // Then you can implement your functionaliton here according to the need. 
    }
```

if you need any other help please let me know by posting the actuall code & requirement over

Comment: Hello, I have solved the problem with the solution shared by Sid Mhatre. Thank's anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is required to add one more key to the push notification payload as `screen_type` based on the content to which screen you need to navigate or show the particular view controller(screen).

After that, add the following method to your AppDelegate class which implements the notifications handler

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    let payload = userInfo
    let type = payload["type"]
    if type == "all-posts" || type == "default"{
        /*
         * I'm assuming you have your own HomeViewController object
         */
        let homeVC = HomeViewController()
        // present or push
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(homeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else if type = "post-details"{
        /*
         * I'm assuming you have your own PostDetailViewController object
         */
        let postDetailVC = PostDetailViewController()
        // present or push
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(postDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else if type == "friend-request"{
        /*
         * I'm assuming you have your own UserViewController object
         */
        let userVC = UserViewController()
        // present or push
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(userVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Helper method

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you are using latest version of *swift*, you are required to implement the **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** methods

Comment: Hello, I have solved the problem with the solution shared by Sid Mhatre. Thank's anyway!